# Pasar una instancia de una clase con datos a otra clase en Java

Tags: java

Tengo una clase con GETTERS y SETTERS de los atributos y deseo pasar la instancia de esta clase con la información que tiene almacenada, a otra clase para poder utilizar sus datos con los GETTERS.

public class Dato_usuarios

```
package datos;

public class Dato_usuarios {

    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String usuario;
    private String contrasena;

    public Dato_usuarios(int id, String nombre, String apellido, String usuario, String contrasena) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public Dato_usuarios() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public String getContrasena() {
        return contrasena;
    }
    public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

}
```

public class Vista_usuarios extends JFrame

```
// Declarada globalmente
// En una parte de esta clase, guardo los datos que el usuario escribe en los JTextField con d_u.setNombre(); etc...
Dato_usuarios d_u = new Dato_usuarios();

JButton btnEditar = new JButton("Editar");
        btnEditar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Instancio la clase a la que quiero pasarle "Dato_usuarios" y su información almacenada
                Vista_editarusuario v_eu = new Vista_editarusuario();
                v_eu.setVisible(true);
                v_eu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                // Le asigno la instancia directamente
                v_eu.d_u = d_u;
            }
        });
```

public class Vista_editarusuario extends JFrame

```
// Declarada globalmente
Dato_usuarios d_u = new Dato_usuarios();
```

Estoy pasando la instancia incorrectamente?
Cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lograr lo que quieres es sencillo, solo debes pasar el objeto que creas de la clase `d_u` a la clase `Vista_editarusuario`. Lo cual, lo puedes hacer utilizando el constructor.

```
JButton btnEditar = new JButton("Editar");
    btnEditar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Instancio la clase a la que quiero pasarle "Dato_usuarios" y su información almacenada
            Vista_editarusuario v_eu = new Vista_editarusuario(d_u); // Pasas el objeto d_u
            v_eu.setVisible(true);
            v_eu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            // Le asigno la instancia directamente
            // v_eu.d_u = d_u;
        }
    });
```

#### Vista_editarusuario

```
public class Vista_editarusuario extends JFrame {

    // Objeto que almacenara el objeto recibido en el cosntructor
    Dato_usuarios d_u;

    // Constructor
    public Vista_editarusuario(Dato_usuarios d_u) {

        // Almacena el objeto recibido en el objeto d_u;
        this.d_u = d_u;
    }

    ...

}
```

## Algunas correcciones

- Las palabras que componen el nombre de tus clases las estas separando con guion bajo (_), lo cual esta mal y dificulta la legibilidad de tu código. Por convención las palabras que componen el nombre de una clase deben comenzar por mayúscula.

  Vista_editarusuario ❌
  VistaEditarUsuario ✔
- Los nombres de las variables deben dar una idea de lo que son, por lo que no es recomendable usar letras o signos. Esta sentencia `v_eu.d_u = d_u;` es particularmente difícil de leer. A los objetos (variables) debes darles nombres significativos, que definan lo que son.

  d_u ❌
  datosUsuario ✔

Comment: Gran explicación!, te agradezco mucho el tiempo que has invertido en ayudarme. Aplicaré tu consejo sobre las correcciones. Otra cosa, he aplicado tu solución, puse el constructor de primero en toda la clase, pero, VistaEditarUsuario no carga. solo aparece la barra de la ventana con los botones de minimizar y cerrar. He colocado el constructor en una mala posición?, dónde debo colocarlo, antes o después del código de Launch the application?. Captura: http://oi67.tinypic.com/2582sea.jpg

Comment: Antes tu ventana se veía bien?

Comment: Sí. VistaEditarUsuario se veía correctamente. No creo que haya problemas con el otro constructor de la clase, el que crea el frame "public Vista_editarusuario() {". Este no recibe nada, el que tu me sugeriste sí, un parámetro, no debería haber problemas, pero, los hay. Qué será....

Comment: Puedes mostrarme como se veía tu clase antes de que le hicieras las modificaciones de la respuesta que te di.

Comment: Seguro, puedes ver VistaEditarUsuario aquí (puedes editar con este enlace): https://codeshare.io/2BOXln. Otra captura: http://oi67.tinypic.com/r8yxas.jpg